# Is there a setting in VS Code to remove new lines before Opening Curly Braces?

Tags: visual-studio-code, formatting

In my style of writing code, I don't prefer having new lines before opening curly braces. For example look at the code below:

```c
int delete(int arr[], int *uSize, int index)
{
    for (int i = index; i < *uSize; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
    }

    *uSize -= 1;
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    int arr[20] = {7, 8, 9, 10, 11};
    int usedSize = 5;

    delete(arr, &usedSize, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

I would rather like to have:

```c
int delete(int arr[], int *uSize, int index) {
    for (int i = index; i < *uSize; i++) {
        arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
    }

    *uSize -= 1;
    return 1;
}

int main() {
    int arr[20] = {7, 8, 9, 10, 11};
    int usedSize = 5;

    delete(arr, &usedSize, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

I tried searching for settings in Visual Studio Code but couldn't find any.

Comment: Which extension do you use for c development? Usually, formatters are provided by the language extension, VSCode doesn't do any formatting by itself.

Comment: @tkausl I use C/C++ Official extension pack by microsoft

Comment: Seems like this extensions uses clang-format, so a `.clang-format` file in the root directory should work. Check https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html for the options.